# AWS Lambda returning empty result queryCommand dynamodb

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to implement a simple QueryCommand using the new javascript v3, as the sample here:
https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/javascriptv3/example_code/dynamodb/actions/document-client/query.js
when I try the following code, I get a 200 answer without any results: (I am using QueryCommand from "@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb";

```
    const command = new QueryCommand({
    TableName: 'my-table',
    KeyConditionExpression:
      'pk = :mydata',
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":myData": "Blah",
    },
    ConsistentRead: true,
  });
console.log(command);
  const response = await docClient.send(command);
console.log(response);

return response.Items
```

this code returns 200 but without any items.
that is the logged query:

```
{"middlewareStack":{},"input":{"TableName":"my-table","KeyConditionExpression":"pk = :mydata","ExpressionAttributeValues":{":mydata":"Blah"},"ConsistentRead":true},"inputKeyNodes":{"KeyConditions":{"":{"AttributeValueList":[]}},"QueryFilter":{"":{"AttributeValueList":[]}},"ExclusiveStartKey":{},"ExpressionAttributeValues":{}},"outputKeyNodes":{"Items":{"*":{}},"LastEvaluatedKey":{}},"clientCommand":{"middlewareStack":{},"input":{"TableName":"my-table","KeyConditionExpression":"pk = :mydata","ExpressionAttributeValues":{":mydata":"Blah"},"ConsistentRead":true}}},"logStream":"$LATEST","requestId":"8fa0b0ee-4fda-4b49-b40e-083c8a2c46ee","version":"$LATEST","mydata":"Blah"}
```

and here is the logged response:

```
{"$metadata":{"httpStatusCode":200,"requestId":"20c448cf-28a4-4c99-b7fe-7a3e296e7388","attempts":1,"totalRetryDelay":0}},"logStream":"$LATEST","requestId":"8fa0b0ee-4fda-4b49-b40e-083c8a2c46ee","version":"$LATEST","mydata":"Blah"}
```

when I try to run the following query in the terminal:

```
aws dynamodb query --table-name my-table --key-condition-expression "pk = :mydata" --expression-atribute-values '{":mydata":{"S":"Blah"}' --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000
```

it returns 3 values. I can't find what I am missing here. ideas?

here is the data on AWS DynamoDB[image: DynamoDB query]

Comment: Both requests are to DynamoDB Local? BTW your awscli query is not valid, as written.

Comment: indeed both are running on local DynamoDB, I forgot to add a ' in the end there(fixed already). I am struggling to see what is wrong in the code there, I tried to deploy on AWS and the same error happened, it returned 200 without any data.

Comment: Where are you actually returning the response? It would help to see the full function instead of just a small slice of your code.

Answer (score 0):

In your CLI code you run against DynamoDB local: `--endpoint-url http://localhost:8000` but it's unclear if your Lambda is running locally or if you are connecting to the web service of DynamoDB.

When DynamoDB returns a 200 with an empty response, it means the request was good but the data simply didn't exist.

1. Check you are running against the correct version of DynamoDB (local/web)
2. Check that you set the correct region
3. Check the web-console for the existence of item Blah if using the web verison

Comment: these were what I thought initially as well, so I added a logic to add some data with the PutCommand, and it worked, so I am not sure why I would be able to insert the data, query it from the terminal and not to be able to query it from the code. I could not see my mistake or what I could be missing. 
The same behaviour happens when I deploy it on AWS, I can insert data, but can't query it. thoughts?

Comment: Have you run the CLI command against the web version? Does it return data?

Comment: I tried the web interface on DynamoDB->Explore Items and I could make the query there.

Comment: Can you update your question to include the image of that request?

Comment: just did, let me know if any ideas. thanks again

Comment: Everything looks good. Do you happen to have any other tables called `my-table` in other regions?

Try run this from Cloudshell: `aws dynamodb query --table-name my-table --key-condition-expression "pk = :mydata" --expression-atribute-values '{":mydata":{"S":"Blah"}' --region <my-region>`

Comment: Sorted, after I upgraded the dependencies yarn upgrade-interactive, it worked, I didn't try to check one by one to see which one was giving me the issue, but it is sorted now. Thanks a lot for your support